# Suggest a domain name.

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name cooking.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Post your ideas for a **dot-com domain name** for this website, which captures the spirit and intent of the site, namely:

> {name} is for cooks, chefs, and anyone who can make a dish that can objectively be described as “mean”.

Please follow these guidelines:

- **Check to see if the domain is taken or squatted *before* making the name suggestion.** Squatted and taken names, however clever, are not helpful. You can use [whois.net](http://www.whois.net) to check availability.
- **Post one domain per answer.** This makes the voting process much easier. If domains are very similar (e.g. "game" and "games"), they can be in the same answer.
- **Make sure the domain wasn't already suggested.** To search within this question, use a search query such as: `inquestion:1 "example.com"` replacing `example.com` with the domain to search for.

Comment: How exactly do we expect these domains to remain untaken if they get popular here? Is meta. currently visible only to the closed beta? If so, I guess we're probably OK.

Comment: Jeff said that this needs to be discussed only during the closed beta, and decided upon before the end of it.

Comment: Enough negative votes?

Comment: does squatted mean registered to the likes of godaddy.com?  Or only things which come up as available in the whois.net search valid?

Comment: What's with all the xoverflow.com's?

Comment: @Brendan Long The original site of this kind was called "Stackoverflow" and was a programming Q&A site. From this a few other sites were spawned, before "Stack Exchange" was created, which is the means by which this site was created by the community.

Comment: @Edd, I know about StackOverflow, I'm just wondering why 90% of the suggestions are almost exact copies of that name. The whole point of "the new stack exchange" is that each site has its own identity.

Comment: @Brendan Long - I know. Personally I'm not going to vote for any stack or overflow (except maybe waffleoverflow, assuming it stands no chance of actually winning)

Answer (score 56):

## seasonedadvice.com

Available

Comment: +1 I like this one.

Comment: This one rose quickly! As long as someone in this community is the one that owns it (GoDaddy says: seasonedadvice.com is already taken. It was registered today.), I think we may have a winner,

Comment: A WhoIs Lookup has it registered to Stack Overflow Internet Services, so it looks like the community has it available if this is what we want to go with.

Comment: Looks like we definitely have a winner.  How high does an answer have to be voted to clinch it?  Somewhere between 30-50 votes perhaps?  Or are we supposed to wait until the end of the beta?

Comment: I think we wait until the end of the beta

Comment: This can be ambiguous. Seas one dad vice - It is hard for me to see seasoned advice in that string.

Comment: I agree that we should wait until the end of beta.

Comment: Most of the time you would find the domain in print would be as **SeasonedAdvice.com**. When spoken, you would say **Seasoned Advice** as two words. Ambiguity is not so much an issue when first telling someone about the domain (though, to be sure, it can be), but rather it is most important that the resulting domain not be ambiguous *and* have avoid having an entirely different meaning. For example, "seas one dad vice" is hardly meaningful; "KitchensExpert," which can be miscontrued as "Kitchen Sexpert," has an altogether different meaning that ought to be avoided.

Comment: +1: Wow. Great choice. This is the first one I haven't voted down.

Comment: @Justin - I saw "Seasoned Advice" in the text straight away, context helped somewhat. I suspect that if someone's searching the 'net for something cooking related and sees "seasonedadvice.com/........" as a result, there's a fair chance they'll get the "humour" of the domain name :) Oh, and +1 for the domain!

Comment: It would be a great choice if advice were actually allowed, but it really seems like everything remotely subjective is being voted down and closed and considered off-topic.  Questions without a single accepted answer are considered bad questions.

Comment: I removed the capitalization as second level domain are lowercase only. This is what the user would actually see.

Comment: @Cade Roux, you can get an objective advice from someone. Advice is not necessarily subjective.

Comment: @rob, yeah, the context helps, and I really like the pun (or w/e it is)  I just want everyone to remember expertsexchange...

Comment: You will not get seasoning advices on this site as it would be banned as subjective and argumentative, so this is a misguiding name!

Comment: @Ben: Great name. I agree, the ambiguity is not really a problem. The worst example I've seen so far is for Math (Maths in British English) where a proposed name was MathsExchange.com (MathSexChange.com?).

Comment: Absolutely wonderful.

Answer (score 26):

## plumpcook.com

A few years ago I saw a refrigerator magnet that says, "Never trust a skinny cook." Ever since then, I've thought there should be a cooking community/site/whatever called **Plump Cook** (plumpcook.com is available.)

Comment: Aside from the fact that I've known many an amazing skinny cook, I love it :)

Comment: I like this. Infinitely memorable. Completely unambiguous. Easily identifiable for what it is.

Comment: It's difficult to understand for a non native English speaker (I bet most non native speakers don't know that plump means fat). fatcook.com would be universally understandable, but of course it isn't as nice.

Comment: How many readers do you think are non-native speakers? (seriously, I'm curious what your estimate is).  It might be worth the slight loss of translation in order to have a very charming and memorable name.  But thanks for adding the minority/global perspective.

Answer (score 17):

## overspiced.com

A few notes here. We really don't know if we have any professional chefs here, or if we will ever get them. We do know that we've got plenty of computer geeks who also happen to cook. If we take a name that implies real chefs and don't deliver, that might not be so good. This name, on the other hand, is likely to just keep pulling in geeks who happen to cook. And those people are, In my opinion, the likeliest to master the mechanics of the stackexchange platform and make the site go.

Comment: I like this one, it fits the theme of StackOverflow and ServerError, in that it is a common issue that someone might have.

Comment: On the minus side, I don't think it has quite the positive connotation of bounty and expertise that, say, SuperUser entails. What perhaps makes StackOverflow and ServerFault work despite the "problematic" nature of their names is that they're terms that you have to have a computer background to fully parse, hence terms that portray the technical literacy of their communities.

Comment: Re geeks vs pros: I think there's a point to that, which is why I wouldn't go with, say, chef in the name. But have some faith in your fellow geeks! I think the q&a so far have been of excellent quality, and demomstrate plenty of knowledge on the subject.

Comment: I dunno, having over-spiced food is rarely a problem for me! How about "UnderSeasoned.com"? (It appears to be a defunct blog...)

Comment: I don't think the theme of StackOverflow is even a little relevant to the naming of a food Q&A site. We should be looking for something that works for food, not a clever connection to SOflow.

Comment: Re the premise outlined above, that "we really don't know if we have any professional chefs here...", I really hope that we *do* get them. No offense to my fellow geeks who arrived here from StackOverflow, but I really hope that this cooking site attracts **experts and professionals** in the domain of food and cooking.  The educational wisdom and insight afforded by a professional is hopefully leaps and bounds above what a mere food enthusiast should provide.  That doesn't say much about the suggested name in this answer, but I disagree strongly with the premise.

Comment: @Ben: frankly, and sadly, I doubt this will ever be a community of experts and professionals chefs. This is a cooking Q&A site built, run and used by IT geeks, and this is obvious looking at its format, layout, procedures, and content...

Comment: Too bad it can't be OldSpice...

Comment: @ziggamorph serverFAULT

Answer (score 10):

## finelydiced.com

Comment: I know I'm nit picking here, but with respective to chopping, doesn't "diced" imply "coarse?"  The name *sounds* good but it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I think it depends on how big the dices are :)

Comment: Diced > Chopped > Finely Chopped. Finely Diced? I don't think that makes sense.

Comment: to me Diced implies shape (cube) and uniformity not size.  Chopped implies less uniformity to me. but chopped could be large and uneven (roughly chopped) or very small (finely chopped)

Comment: Well, you have now coarsely chopped this suggestion. What can I tell you? It just sounded good to me, and 11 people apparently agree.

Comment: That's a very cleaver play on words.

Comment: -1: This name is **very** difficult to understand for non native English speakers.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Just curious, why is it so difficult?

Answer (score 6):

### meandish.com

(available)

Comment: The team should grab this one ASAP.  It's short, catchy, easy-to-remember, clearly about cooking, and (IMO) speaks to professionals and home cooks alike.  I'm surprised that it isn't already taken.  Even if we don't end up using it, I'd hate to find out at the last minute that somebody squatted it while it was posted here.

Comment: I read it first time as "Me and ..." and then realised my error and had to re-parse it. I think it is also fairly US-specific, as whilst in Britain we would know what it means, we wouldn't use the term "mean" as much as I understand it is used state-side. I think we'd have to check whether other regions would also understand (especially those from where the users have English as a second language).

Answer (score 4):

## Chefhat.com

An icon of experience as well as a metaphor for attempting to give advice ("let me put my chefhat on...").

Appears available or squatted but not in primary use.

Answer (score 3):

## 99cooks.com

Available.

Comment: I'm happy to report spoiledbroth.com is open for business as well. :-D

Comment: As in, I got 99 problems but being a cook ain't one?

Comment: Does 99 qualify as too many cooks in the kitchen?

Comment: @Mike Sherov: I got 99 problems but a kitch(en) ain't one.

I'll be here all week, folks. Tip your waitress.

Comment: 99cooks.com seems taken to me...

Comment: @Sam: I think team policy is to register any likely candidates so that they don't get "stolen" during the beta period.  See Jeff's response on MetaSO [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55855/website-naming-discussion-should-not-be-public/55903#55903).

Comment: I don't like the "99"... what does it means? Why not 88cooks (like the Crazy 88 from KB) or 69cooks (like the 69 sex position)?

Comment: @Lorenzo: why not 69cooks? Gee, I don't know. That wouldn't possibly make people think it's anything other than a cooking related site.

Comment: Too many cooks spoil the broth. The faq should say "Get half of them out of the kitchen".

Comment: Everytime I see a RandomNumberPlusAWord.com domain name, it seems like an attempt to piggy-back on the easy recognition of sites like 37signals or 43folders. I could go without seeing another RandomNumberPlusAWord domain name.  That's not to say those sites aren't easily recognized, but I think we can do better.

Comment: I strongly dislike 99designs, so no.

Comment: The key to the number/word names is a) that the number is random and b) that the second word is generic but not bland.  Cooks is bland.  Folders has some interest to it (what's in the folder? hints at organization) (signal refers to signal/noise ratio, a key concept in programming/communication).  If this were to work it needs a better number and a better word. As is it just says "a lot of cooks".  101chefs might be more interesting, if it doesn't suggest amateurs.

Comment: @Ocaasi: 101chefs.com. Sounds good. Try suggesting it.

Comment: What about 99chefs.com 

It's more, chef-y, and available too.

Answer (score 3):

## superchef.com

Well, it's <strike>available</strike> not in use...

Answer (score 3):

### **[cooksqa.com](http://cooksqa.com)**

Available. Perfectly captures what is going on with this site.

Answer (score 2):

## steakoverflow.com

(Too geeky, I know, but too bad a pun not to share)

Comment: I'm not upvoting this but it's indeed a nice one :)

Answer (score 2):

Chef Complete

## ChefComplete.com

Available.

Answer (score 2):

## Clarifiedbutter.com

Butter is delicious.  Clarified is refined.  And explained.  And mainly chefs do it.

edit: 'It's not exactly available'.  Maybe clarifiedcook.com, clarifiedchef.com, or clarifiedkitchen.com

Answer (score 1):

## hardboiledchef.com

(or hardboiledcook.com)

Comment: Sounds very Dashiell Hammett.

Comment: Perhaps softboiledchef?

Answer (score 1):

## foodtotaste.com

Available

Comment: Preparing food "to taste" is a sign that your cooking skills have gone beyond merely following a recipe. There's also a slight *double entendre* in that the name could be interpreted as "food to be tasted," but experts in the domain of cooking are familiar with the phrase "to taste," so the name hints at something beyond simple food preparation.

Answer (score 1):

## 101chefs.com

More than a hundred says a lot.
101 says, learning and open to beginners.
Chefs says, aiming for expertise not just recipes.

It's available.

Answer (score 1):

### howtocook.com

I'm aware that the domain is currently registered, but it appears to go "nowhere" other than a "Sponsored Listings" page at present, so the StackExchange bods might be able to procure it.

It's clear, concise, pun-free and would have fairly immediate appeal in search results. If I was google/bing-ing "how do I cook a rare steak" and the first or second result was from "howtocook.com", I'd probably go straight for that one!

Answer (score 0):

### funsoup.com

available

Answer (score 0):

## Chefweb.com

Self-explanatory.  Chefs.  Networked.

It's available... (squatted landing site).

Comment: Squatted != available, unfortunately.

Comment: Aren't those sites typically open to conversion (purchase).  They're all over the place... how much do you think it could cost to grab one?

Comment: If the beta is successful and the owner gets wind of why somebody wants it, it would cost a lot. The reason people squat these domains is so they can hold anyone who wants them hostage.

Comment: Well, if it makes the short-list, it might be worth finding out what the cost is.  Definitely before the final vote.

Answer (score 0):

Cheftastic.com

(for sale, godaddy)

edit note: other brainstorms were moved to comments, since this is the only one that received vote-interest

Comment: FYI, we're looking for domains that aren't registered, so no squatted / parked / for sale domains.

Comment: i might extract cheftastic.com

Comment: @mfg will do.  feel free to vote on it, although there's something close to consensus on this page already

Comment: TastyChef.com (for sale), 
SousChef.com (squatted), 
Chefshelper.com (for sale),

Answer (score 0):

techchef.com (or cheftech.com)

both available

Answer (score -1):

How does

**cookaroo.com**

sounds to you?

(yes, it's available)

Answer (score -1):

Alas, toomanycooks.com is squatted.

So, I see, is tomanycooks.com.

but

### frommanycooks.com

is available!

Answer (score -1):

Spicerack.com

emphasizes variety, tools, flavor

edit: not available, though variations might be

Answer (score -1):

So I've been thinking about the focus of the site, and how we want it to be about techniques rather than recipes so with that in mind the following are all available, on a similar theme and in the order I prefer them.

- cookerytechnique.com
- cookstechniques.com
- cooktechnique.com

Comment: what about: cooktech, cheftech, kitchentech, foodtech, or inversed (techcook, techchef, techkitchen, techfood)

Answer (score -1):

techfood.com (or foodtech.com)

both available

Answer (score -1):

**spicyquestions.com** (available)

Kind of like seasonedadvice, but different. Not as 'misreadable' as seasonedadvice. More intriguing (IMHO).

- Relevant to cooking (obviously), relevant to questions, name suggests an interesting site
- Cooking's more than spices alone, the wrong kind of 'spicy question' may be inferred at first glance (good? bad?).

Related, but less strong (IMHO): saucyquestions.com

Edit: I notice seasonedadvice has already been registered by SO. I'll leave the suggestion here for posterity though.

Answer (score -1):

## stovetopbuffet.com

Stovetop Buffet: The Cook's Q&A

Available, and the ascenders make it easy to read.

Answer (score -1):

whimsicalcookery.com/

(available)

Comment: boo-hoo. was i down-voted because this is similar to the regretsy motto, or because i failed to mention the similarity?

Answer (score -2):

### heatandspices.com

(available)

Comment: Sounds like a store..

Answer (score -2):

## inquiretotaste.com

Available

Answer (score -2):

## cookinginquiry.com

Available

Answer (score -2):

## bustedegg.com

'Cuz crackedeggs.com was taken

Answer (score -2):

How about:

## smartskillet.com / smartskillet.net

The owner of these domains just emailed me and said that he initially registered them with plans for his own Stack Exchange 1.0 site, but didn't find the time to get it going. He's offered to transfer them over for this site's use if we want them.

I think it's a pretty snappy name. And for those saying that the word "skillet" is "too American", I invite you to look at [it's etymology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skillet):

> Main Entry: **skil·let** 
> Pronunciation: \ˈski-lət\ 
> Function: *noun* 
> Etymology: Middle English *skelet*, probably from Anglo-French **escuelete*, diminutive of *escuelle*, *eskil* bowl — more at scullery 
> Date: 15th century 
> **1** chiefly British : a small kettle or pot usually having three or four often long feet and used for cooking on the hearth 
> **2** : frying pan

The word has been around since the 15th century, which is before America was even discovered. Besides, **smartwok.com**, though not as alliterative as **smartskillet.com**, would be perfectly acceptable too, in spite of the Asian origins of the term 'wok'.

Comment: skillet is a bit of an American term, not really generic enough in my opinion

Comment: As a Brit, I have to say that whilst the term is used in both countries, the meaning varies and what I believe you would call a skillet is what we'd call a frying pan. What I'd call a skillet is something like http://www.lecreuset.co.uk/PageFiles/3421/Panini_PressSKilletGrillSe.jpg which isn't used nearly as often and is more of a specialist piece of equipment.

Answer (score -2):

## AddSaltToTaste.com

Available

Answer (score -2):

## 100pleats.com

Available

Based on [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/why-do-chefs-traditionally-wear-a-high-white-hat/3268#3268) about the origin of the Chef's hat.

Comment: Admittedly, this violates my preference to avoid "number + word" domain names, but the number 100 is signicant in that 100 pleats represents the "ultimate" number to have in a chef's hat.  See the link above for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Many Pleats

## manypleats.com

Available

Inspiration comes from [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/why-do-chefs-traditionally-wear-a-high-white-hat/3268#3268) where the number of pleats in a chef's hat supposedly indicates his expertise.

Answer (score -2):

TwoTaste.com

-riffs on "to taste", the chef's seasoning rule
-suggests collaboration, two mouths better than one

Answer (score -2):

Boiledpeanuts.com

-ironic southern (American) regional snack, self-mockingly bland

-suggests the idiosyncratic community, many chefs/nuts roiling around in a liquid

Answer (score -3):

**theexpertchefs.com**

Comment: +1, except that I'd drop "the" and have it be http://expertchefs.com

Comment: That's taken, Dave...

Comment: I would avoid theexpertchefs.com if expertchefs.com is taken.

Answer (score -3):

overcooked.com

:-)

Comment: Squatted domain.  So is overdone.com.

Answer (score -3):

chefbeat.com   The "beat" is both a cooking verb, as well as meaning "regularly traversed round", so a place to visit regularly.

Answer (score -3):

kitchensexperts.com

:P

Comment: The embedded 3-letter word starting with 's' might get blocked by overzealous filters.

Comment: @flicken, it's a play on expertsexchange.com (the dreadful site which helped spawn Stack Overflow's original existence)

Comment: @AGabriel, I doubt outsiders will be aware of the connection.

Comment: It was a tongue-in-cheek suggestion.

Comment: Bad suggestion in my opinion since the "sex" part can be caught in URL filters.

Comment: Simple. Add a hyphen to it so the word seperation is clear. Hyphen-site 2.0! (8-p)

Answer (score -3):

I am sharing this for humor sake only. As I wrote up a list of ideas, this one seemed okay at first, then I realized it was just not going to work:

cooksexchange.com

The site for all culinary experts considering a change of gender! (It's taken.)

Comment: Or perhaps how to make your own home-brewed sex change?

Answer (score -3):

## 99Kitchens.com

Available.

Trying to think of terminology that is *more* inclusive than "cooks," "chefs," "bakers," etc that seem to suggest a certain type of activity in the kitchen. Ah, "kitchen" covers them all.

Comment: What's with the number "99"?  I don't get that.

Comment: Nothing in particular. Just a memorable, somewhat-catchy way to make the domain unique.

Comment: one less than 100!  99% - just conjures up an image in ones mind.

Answer (score -3):

ask-cooking.com

Answer (score -3):

foodoverflow.com

Comment: No need to copy StackOverflow on everything..

Comment: @Brendan: it's nice the image of the food overflowing.

Answer (score -3):

**fivespice.com**

or

**5spice.com**

Answer (score -3):

## KitchenConundrums.com

Available.

Answer (score -4):

ask-the-chefs.com

Answer (score -4):

cakeflop.com

Not registered as of the time of this posting.

Answer (score -4):

kitchenoverflow.com

Answer (score -4):

cookeryquestions.com

There's actually a stack-exchange site with this name, but it's only got three questions on it. Maybe the person who set up the original site could be persuaded to give the domain name over.

Answer (score -4):

## meancookery.com

Available

Answer (score -4):

**PotOverflow**

Answer (score -4):

http://www.mypotoverfloweth.com/

or hyphenate...

Answer (score -4):

allofyourfoodandcookingquestionsanswered.com

Answer (score -5):

<strike>stackburner.com  (well, backburner was taken...)</strike>  Withdrawn, see comment by Tesserex.

Comment: Doesn't shout "cooking" to an outsider.

Comment: Good point. I'll strike out.

Answer (score -5):

foodrocks.com

:)

Comment: Taken already...

Answer (score -5):

boiloverflow.com

Inspired by when your pot "boils over"

Answer (score -5):

The term 'hob' seems to be generic enough to eliminate any confusion.

offthehob.com

Comment: Hob isn't a common term in the U.S.  In fact, I've never heard it used before.  Out of curiosity, where is it in common usage?

Comment: It's British English, which is my second language and I assumed it would translate to American English, clearly it doesn't :)

Answer (score -6):

boiledaway.com

is another.

Answer (score -6):

underthebroiler.com

Comment: A broiler is called a grill outside America.

Answer (score -6):

emulsifiedanswers.com

Answer (score -7):

blenderoverflow.com

Answer (score -8):

flavoroverflow.com

Comment: That includes an American spelling. Best to avoid to reduce confusion.

Answer (score -9):

popoverflow.com

Comment: I both like this, and wanted to do something nice for you since you created the least liked suggestion on this thread.