# Food and Cooking logo?

Tags: feature-request, logo

When and how is this Stack Exchange going to get a logo? #5 on [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) clearly says we should be thinking about this. Is [Jin Yang](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) going to make it? Am I jumping the gun since we [don't yet have a non-stackexchange domain](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's any harm in discussing the logo, certainly, if anyone has any designs they wish to put forward, I would be very interested in seeing them.

Answer (score 3):

It is a tad early. I'd worry more about the domain name, since that will tend to color what the logo becomes.