# What should our logo look like?

Tags: discussion, logo, design

It seems pretty clear that we are leaning towards [SeasonedAdvice.com](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name) (Great Name!). With that said, I think it's time to start soliciting logo design and concepts. Please keep this to the same format as the domain name thread: Community Wiki, one design/suggestion per answer.

Comment: Is there some place that we can see all of the existing logos in one place, at a decent size?  (I know I can look at the people listings on Area 51, but they're pretty small)

Comment: I had assumed that part of the $6MM raised would go toward a contest at 99designs or similar, with the community voting here on the best one.

Answer (score 5):

I just had a totally crazy idea.  Unfortunately I have no artistic talent to actually *follow through* with it but try to use your imaginations:

Everybody is familiar with the "Rubin's Vase" optical illusion, right?

[image: Vase or Two Faces?]
([Source](http://www.squidoo.com/optical-illusion-images))

Well, it occurred to me just how much this profile looks like a traditional-style pepper mill:

[image: Pepper Mill]
([Source](http://www.kitchenzing.com/product.php?pcode=SP0118RD))

Could we somehow combine these two themes, and add some detail so that the "faces" aspect is a little more obvious?  You know, sort of like...

[image: Mac OS Logo]

But obviously with the pepper-mill outline and more appropriate colours (IIRC, Jin says that most cookbooks use 2-3 of red, orange, green, blue, and white, and that seems to mirror my own experience).

The pepper mill symbolizes the "seasoning" obviously, and the faces represent the "community."

What do you think?  Does it sound interesting?  Could we do it?  Has it already been done?

Comment: I can't quite picture anything yet, but I like the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but I just can't hack it.  I'm not suggesting that the result actually has to be an optical illusion; rather, something a bit like the Mac OS logo but forming the outline of a pepper mill with the black strokes.  Obviously this would all have to be stylized - symbolic and not entirely realistic - so my moderate Photoshop skills are useless here.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to mimic the SO logo, except:

1. the container for the stack is now a pot. (should maybe have a fire underneath? I couldn't draw it).
2. The overflowing stack is instead spices and seasoning being thrown in.
3. A hand is added to indicate seasoning the dish.

I submit this drawing in the time honored tradition of MSPaint Abuse:

[image: SeasonedAdvice.com logo]

Comment: haha, that is great.  Exactly like that gets my vote.  Long live the three fingered!

Comment: That's basically what I pictured, too - except maybe a book instead of a pot as the base.

Comment: haha, I like it. It might be too busy though.

Comment: I like the idea of mimicking the SO logo - Maybe it could be adapted to a pancake, on a skillet, being flipped?

Comment: I don't like the idea of mimicking the SO logo - this is not a cooking site *for programmers*, it's a cooking site, unconnected to SO.

Comment: @Blogbeard, I respect and agree with that opinion. My reason for mimicking the SO logo is that it's a signpost for those coming from SO or other trilogy sites, while at the same time has no connection to programming. People coming here who know nothing about SE won't know it's connected in the slightest to SO by a parent company.

Comment: @Mike, I'd think the appearance of the front page layout would be a pretty good sign that its an SE site. Of course, I have no objection to a good logo that happens to resemble the SO logo - I just don't really think the goal should be to mimick SO's one.

Answer (score 3):

I think a simple chef's hat will do:

[image: chef's hat]

I have no artistic capabilities. This was drawn with my finger on an iPad. Don't laugh >:)

Comment: I'm all for the Chef's hat. Classic and very meaningful.

Comment: Pretty damned good for finger drawing on an iPad :D

Answer (score 2):

I kind of like, though am not married to, the idea of a knife as the logo. As in, the collective wisdom around her carves away the dross, leaving only the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If we're going for 'Seasoned Advice', I'd keep it simple, and go with a salt shaker. (or some other seasoning, technically, it's hard to tell at that scale).

Yes, I know, lots of chefs don't use salt shakers because you can't get as fine of control, but it'd more readily apparent to people what it is, at least from America ... it might not work as well for countries that either don't use salt directly (eg, Asian countries, where soy sauce is the main salt additive).

Comment: I don't think we should necessarily approach it with the mindset of making the logo match the site name. Of the big 3 only SO has a logo that _clearly_ matches the site name, SF sort of does if you look at it hard enough, and SU totally doesn't. I'd be interested in seeing what gets suggested without necessarily trying to match it to SeasonedAdvice.

Comment: @hobodave, just for the record, SU's logo is a face made up of two symbols that are commonly used in programming or configuration files: [}.

Comment: @Mike: I know. It still doesn't indicate "super user" to me, nor does super user lead me to those two symbols. :)

Comment: I LOVE the name "seasoned advice" but I wish the 2nd word started with "P." it'd be great to have a salt and pepper shaker be the first letter of each respective word.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer something perhaps more abstract. The logo for [OpenSourceFood](http://www.opensourcefood.com/) is very clever, implying an egg without obviously being an egg. Something that implies food without actually being a salt shaker or a chef's hat.