# Any better name for this platform?

Tags: discussion, language

I've just joined this platform. Cooking is my passion. Loving the chef's hat logo, it's related to the subject but not very keen on the word 'Seasoned' and noticed the word 'cooking' had to be in bracket underneath. Would it be better to be called Culinary Advise? As culinary is from Latin, culinarius, ''pertaining to the kitchen'' from culina, ''kitchen, food''. My apology this is not a question about cooking but I do not know where to address the suggestion to?

Comment: These types of questions are encouraged at the "meta" version of every site: this is the "Cooking.SE" site ([cooking.se]), where the meta is "Meta.Cooking.SE" ([meta.cooking.se]). Users with some amount of reputation can post there to discuss the workings of the site (I think the threshold is 125 rep). Welcome to [se]! Consider also [the tour](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) or see the [help] for more information about the site.

Answer (score 11):

"Seasoned" has two meanings, which makes it very appropriate for this site.

One of the main goals of Stack Exchange is to attract professionals and experts in the subjects. One definition of "[seasoned](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/seasoned)" is "experienced".

> used to describe someone who has a lot of experience of a particular thing

The other definition relates more to cooking directly, meaning that it's well-flavored.

This clever double meaning really does a great job of describing the site and its purpose.

Answer (score 3):

What is StackOverflow about? (Hint: not overflowing stacks.) What is ServerFault about? When this network of sites first started, each site had a catchy name that was not simply a description of what it was about. This pattern continued with the first few sites that were not about software development. Cooking.StackExchange.com isn't just called "cooking" - it has a fun name, a pun, that someone took quite a while to come up with. Gaming.StackExchange.com is called Arqade.

There are two problems with this approach: one is that it's really hard to come up with these names, and the other is that people don't always "get" the names afterwards. So these days sites get boring names like Travel or Parenting. The name of **this** site is a historical holdover from the days of "neat" names. If it were to be changed at all (which I doubt) it would almost certainly be changed to just plain "Cooking" because that's the new normal.

Answer (score 2):

As @Joe said in a comment, which seems to have vanished during the migration of this question to Meta, the name was the winner of the naming contest, culminating in the name Seasoned Advice. For a glimpse at history, they live at

- [The Elevator Pitch](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline), and
- The (deprecated, closed) [previous, seminal question on Meta.Cooking.SE](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name)