# Is Seasoned Advice a misleading title?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for this SE site in the pull down list from the header, and was surprised to find it wasn't under "F" for Food, "G" for Gastronomy or "C" for Cooking, but Seasoned Advice.

I like a pun as much as the next man, but isn't the title a little confusing?

And if we do want a pun for a title, why not "Snack Overflow"? ;)

Comment: For some reason I really, really want Snack Overflow to be a real site. In fact, searching Area 51 for that phrase (in vain hope) was how I found this site. I'd also like to see one about pro wrestling (or maybe illegal substances?) called Smack Overflow.

Comment: See also: http://imgur.com/dD7woKo

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's a little confusing in certain cases, but it's probably not worth changing at this point; it's been our name for quite a long time and as far as we know hasn't caused any large issues.

The summary is that for a very short period of time, StackExchange let newly launched sites pick cute names, and was going to let them be used as *domain names*. Very quickly they thought better of this, and still let them be used as titles/taglines, and then eventually decided to stick with obvious titles as well. There was of course a lot of debate and drama at every stage of this process. There are now a few exceptions (askubuntu, arqade...) but I think they're generally reserved for cases where they think unique branding will help the site. At this point, unless there are some *really* convincing reasons, I think everything's going to stay the way it is.

As for the question in the title, I wouldn't say it's misleading (I don't think anyone has any doubt we're a cooking site), but it does I suppose in some cases reduce discoverability as you found. The search in the dropdown does still bring it up for "cooking", though it doesn't for "food" - if you want to post a question asking for that, it's probably a good idea. (I'm not particularly worried about it being discoverable via "gastronomy".)

Some further reading:

- [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)
- [Suggest a domain name.](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name)

Answer (score 2):

Protip: Type "cooking" into the search box in the pulldown menu. It shows Seasoned Advice, with the tagline "for professional and amateur chefs".

In my opinion that's pretty clear. Sorry if you disagree. We worked hard to get our branding and I don't think anyone's going to be overly keen to give it up.